# How to check if two sets are identical in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2, set

I am using Swift and have two sets, say:

```
var setA: set<Int>
var setB: set<Int>
```

How to compare these two sets to see if they are identical (having the same elements regardless of the order)?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[`Set`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set) [conforms](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set#relationships) to [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable), so you can just do this:

```
if setA == setB {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is this still the case for Swift 5?

Comment: @BradThomas Yes.

Answer (score 6):

["a set A is a subset of a set B, or equivalently B is a superset of A, if A is "contained" inside B, that is, all elements of A are also elements of B. A and B may coincide."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset)

There fore you could check if A is a subset of B and vise versa.

```
let abcSet: Set = ["Chips", "Sandwiches", "Salad"]
var foodSet = Set(["Salad", "Chips", "Sandwiches"])


abcSet.isSubsetOf(foodSet); // true
foodSet.isSubsetOf(abcSet); // true
```